# Can you link an array variable with a control?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, controls, picturebox

I am making a program with PictureBox controls. It would be easiest to manage the things I want to do with the PictureBox controls if they were in an array already.

This is what I have tried.

```
Sub drawtiles()
    For x As Integer = 0 To 32 Step 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To 24 Step 1
            Dim tile As New PictureBox()
            tile.Width = 20
            tile.Height = 20
            tile.Top = y * 20
            tile.Left = x * 20
            tile.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
            Dim r As Random = New Random
            ' Get random numbers between 1 and 3.
            ' ... The values 1 and 2 are possible.
            Dim s As Integer = (r.Next(1, 3))
            If s = 1 Then
                tile.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.g1774
            Else
                tile.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.rect881

            End If
            tiles(x)(y) = tile
            Controls.Add(tile)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

... with the array being made here

```
Public Class Form1
    Public tiles As Array
```

So, how would I assign the Picturebox control, to the 3d array value?

Comment: Assigning your array to a public field is dodgy. Whatever you plan to do with that, don't. Use the array inside that form only. If you need to initiate processing of that array from outside, provide a public method that can be called and then use the array inside that method.

Comment: Maybe someone would like to include in his answer a word about this `tile.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.g1774`.  Make it perfect :)

Comment: @JQSOFT, I had meant to mention that, but probably not for the reason you mean. It's not really the crux of the question so doesn't really belong in an answer, but does deserve a mention. Firstly, I'm guessing that you are referring to the fact that that code almost certainly should be setting the `Image` property rather than the `BackgroundImage` property. Not sure why so many people seem to make that mistake but it's definitely at least partly a lack of due diligenece, i.e. they clearly haven't bothered to read about the `PictureBox` control.

Comment: oh yeah. Will change the code later. Cheers

Comment: My other point was that the code should almost certainly not be using those `My.Resources` properties over and over again. Doing so creates a new `image` object every time, which is resource-intensive and almost certainly not needed. Instead, those properties should be used once and once only, with the results assigned to variables and those variables used multiple times. That way, the code creates two `Image` objects instead of 825 of them.

Comment: Since you have hardcoded amount of tiles - use `TableLayoutPanel` with required amount of cells(tile) and `PictureBox` control in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost never declare something as type `Array`. That is really only for when you want to be able to refer to an array of any type. That usually only happens with method parameters but, since the advent of generics, you can just write a generic method where the generic type parameter is the type of the array, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub ProcessArray(Of T)(array As T())
    For i = 0 To array.GetUpperBound(0)
        'Process element at index i here.
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want an array of `PictureBoxes` then create a `PictureBox` array. Also, don't use a jagged array when you should be using a 2D array. This is a jagged array of `PictureBoxes`:

```vb
Private jaggedArrays As PictureBox()()
```

and this is a 2D array:

```vb
Private twoDimensionalArray As PictureBox(,)
```

The difference is that the second is a single object whereas the first is a 1D array containing multiple 1D arrays.

You should be creating the array like this:

```vb
Private tiles(32, 24) As PictureBox
```

And then populating it like this:

```vb
For i = 0 To tiles.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j = 0 To tiles.GetUpperBound(1)
        Dim tile As New PictureBox

        '...

        tiles(i, j) = tile
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Never ever ever use `Array` as a type name in VB.Net. Instead, you would declare it like this:

```
 Public tiles() As PictureBox
```

Or this:

```
Public tiles(32*24) As PictureBox
```

Or this (probably your best fit):

```
Public tiles(32, 24) As PictureBox
```

Or this:

```
Public tiles As New List(Of PictureBox)
```

Or skip the extra array altogether, put the controls inside a Panel or GroupBox container, and write code like this when you need to find them:

```
For Each tile As Picturebox in TilePanel.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
    ' ...
Next
```

Remember, with the move to the .Net ecosystem, VB now works so much better when things are strongly-typed. `Option Strict` really should be `On`, and you want very specific type names.